# Configure Apache Web Server with Tomcat and trying to Deploy war file

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, centos

I am not getting my project on my domain name. It gives me Apache Test Page instead of my project which i have added in `webapps`.

I have my war file **FINAL_WE.war** in `/opt/code/apache-tomcat-8.5.54/webapps/`

And I have started my tomcat server. using `sh startup.sh` from /bin/ folder.

Log gives me `tail -f catalina.out`

```
20-Apr-2020 04:06:13.733 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
20-Apr-2020 04:06:13.837 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Apr-2020 04:06:13.879 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Apr-2020 04:06:13.909 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1307 ms
20-Apr-2020 04:06:14.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
20-Apr-2020 04:06:14.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.54
20-Apr-2020 04:06:14.038 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/code/apache-tomcat-8.5.54/webapps/FINAL_WE.war]
20-Apr-2020 04:06:14.602 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/code/apache-tomcat-8.5.54/webapps/FINAL_WE.war] has finished in [564] ms
20-Apr-2020 04:06:14.609 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Apr-2020 04:06:14.623 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 714 ms
```

I have executed the following commands

```
1. cd /usr/local/apache/modules
2. cd /usr/local/apache/conf
3. vim workers.properties

worker.list=we-matter

worker.we-matter.type=ajp13
worker.we-matter.port=8009
worker.we-matter.host=192.169.217.121

4. Apache Web Server file:
vim /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf

LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile  /usr/local/apache/conf/workers.properties

JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    emerg
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T %p %q %r %v %U"


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.we-matter.com
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /we-matter/$1 [L,PT]
    JkMount  /* we-matter
</VirtualHost>


6. service httpd stop
     service httpd start
```

Comment: Linking to your site (in case it is - I'm not going to click it) will render this question invalid once you've fixed your problem. I'd also consider it as spam. Please describe if it's the "Tomcat" or "Apache httpd" test page or post its text here and remove the link.

Comment: @OlafKock, I am getting Apache 2 Test Page

Comment: Indeed - that's the link I consider spam - and once your problem is fixed, the link will not be demonstrating your question any more. The question stays here forever (unless closed as spam) and should be valuable for anyone with the same problem you have.

Comment: @OlafKock, I would update the question then.

Comment: You've now edited out the link, but missed the description: Is it the Tomcat test page? Also: What configuration did you do that made you expect to see your application when you enter your domain name? Finally, if your question is relevant to the [tag:apache] tag: Read the tag's description and edit the question to provide relevant information. I've been removing it for the third time, because there's no hint in your question that this tag is relevant.

Comment: @OlafKock I am configure Apache Web Server with Tomcat and trying to Deploy war file.

Comment: "Configure Apache Webserver" is not quite enough information. I'm configuring it as well, and don't experience any issues. Please provide a [mcve] by editing your question, not by commenting under it.

Comment: @OlafKock, I have installed and configure using following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKqsmnXt_aw

Comment: You don't expect me to watch a 20 minute video in order to help you, right? As it is, I'm voting to close this question because you're asking for debugging help without providing the required information _in the question itself_. So far it says that you're doing _something_, so in order to solve your problem, you should do _something different_ - that's the available level of detail based on the information you provide. SO already suggests moving this comment thread to chat, but I'm out now. Chat would imply that I'm willing to ask even more individual clarification questions, which I won't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212072/discussion-between-maqsud-inamdar-and-olaf-kock).

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a named virtual host in Apache httpd.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.upyourcode.com
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /upyourcode/$1 [L,PT]
    JkMount  /* upyourcode
</VirtualHost>
```

This will cover every request coming in with the Host header to `www.upyourcode.com`. Any other host name will fall back to the default virtual host, which likely does not have your `JkMount` configuration, but is rather configured to the default content, e.g. httpd's "Success" page, rather than your own content.

You'll need to either configure the default virtual host, add a `ServerAlias` to the virtual host you mention in this question, or add yet another virtual host with the `ServerName` that you're expecting to see your content on.